# How to compare an user input guess with their previous guess?

Tags: processing

I've been tasked to write a basic guessing game, which I have done, but part of the task is confusing me.  We've been asked to create a warning when a user inputs the same guess too many times.  I've tried several ways to take the previous user guess and compare them with the current one but none seem to work.  Can anyone help me with this?  My Google skills seem to have failed me.

Mostly I've tried this:

```java
    void guessWarning(int confirmedGuess){
      int prevGuess = currentGuess;
      int currentGuess = confirmedGuess;

    if(prevGuess == currentGuess){
      text("Same guess, try again",350,350)
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to tackle this.

One option would be keep track of the previous attempts in a dynamic array (see [ArrayList](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html)). Here a bit of code to illustrate the concept:

```
//create a new list of integers
ArrayList<Integer> guesses = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//in your check function, test if the new value already exists
if(guesses.contains(NEW_GUESS_HERE)){
  println("you've already tried this number");
}else{//otherwise add the current guess to keep track of for next time
  guesses.add(NEW_GUESS_HERE);
}
```

Another option is using a [HashMap](https://processing.org/reference/HashMap.html). This is an associative array as opposed to an index based array. This method is more efficient and you can also keep track of how many attempts there were for each value. Be sure to read more on [HashMaps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html): it will help you on the long run and potentially impress your tutors on the short run.

Here's a basic sketch to illustrate the idea:

```
//create a new hashmap of integers (key = guess, value = number of times tried)
HashMap<Integer,Integer> guesses = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

int answer = '=';

void setup(){}
void draw(){}
void keyPressed(){
  guess(keyCode);
  println(keyCode);
}

void guess(int newValue){
  if(newValue == answer){
    println("you guessed it!");
  }else{
    //check if the value was already recorded
    try{
      //if there was a value with this key, it's been tried before
      int numberOfTries = guesses.get(newValue);

      println("you've tried this value",numberOfTries,"times");
      //increment the number of times this has beeen attempted
      guesses.put(newValue,numberOfTries+1);

    }catch(NullPointerException e){
      println("it's the first time you try this number, but you haven't guessed it yet");
      guesses.put(newValue,1);
    }
  }
}
```

A similar option, but a bit more hacky would be using a [JSONObject](https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject_getInt_.html).
The concept is similar: an associative array (albeit the key is a string, instead of an int), but you'd need to convert the guessed number to a string to index it first:

```
JSONObject guesses = new JSONObject();

int answer = '=';

void setup(){}
void draw(){}
void keyPressed(){
  guess(keyCode);
  println(keyCode);
}

void guess(int newValue){
  if(newValue == answer){
    println("you guessed it!");
  }else{
    //hacky int to string
    String newValueStr = newValue+"";
    //check if the value was already recorded
    if(guesses.hasKey(newValueStr)){
      //if there was a value with this key, it's been tried before
      int numberOfTries = guesses.getInt(newValueStr);

      println("you've tried this value",numberOfTries,"times");
      //increment the number of times this has beeen attempted
      guesses.setInt(newValueStr,numberOfTries+1);

    }else{
      println("it's the first time you try this number, but you haven't guessed it yet");
      guesses.setInt(newValueStr,1);
    }
  }
}
```

One nice thing is that you could [save](https://processing.org/reference/saveJSONObject_.html) the guesses to disk, then [load](https://processing.org/reference/loadJSONObject_.html) it so the program could recall previous guesses even if the it was restarted.
I'll leave you the fun exercise of attempting to load the data when the sketch starts and saving the data when the sketch exists.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I actually got the code to work right after I posted this but I got distracted by housework afterwords and forgot to change the post.  What you've answered will certainly help my classmates though.  They're stuck too :D